# App build from xcode 6.4 not opening properly in os x 10.9

Tags: macos, xcode6, osx-mavericks

I made a new Mac Project and Code Signed it and export it as Developer ID-signed Application. It is perfectly running on later 10.9. But on 10.9 it only appears in Dock but doesn't comes to foreground. Only the name of App is appear in status bar no other options shown. Please guide me through this issue.

Thanks

Comment: What is the deployment target for the project? If you created a new project in Xcode 6.4, the deployment target was probably set to 10.10, which means your app will not run on 10.9. In this case you will have to set the project's deployment target to 10.9 from the project editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to Create Project from "Xcode 5.1" and Check it will work.